# Set theoretic universe in consistency proofs

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am having difficulties understanding the relative consistency proof $Con(ZF)\rightarrow Con(ZFC)$. Most authors seem to assume at the outset the existence of some universe $V$ satisfying $ZF$ and proceed to show that $L$ is a model for $ZFC$, thus proving the consistency of $ZFC$. Is this universe $V$ assumed to be a set in some larger universe, in which we use the completeness theorem to show that $Con(ZF)$ implies the existence of $V$, or is there some finitistic way of showing $Con(ZF)$ implies the existence of a universe where $ZF$ holds? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this:

**Model-theoretically**: Since ZF is assumed to be consistent, it has a model, and within this model we find a model of ZFC.

This may seem a bit fishy, because the usual proof of the completeness theorem (a consistent theory has a model) used the axiom of choice, but actually the completeness theorem for a *countable* theory such as ZF does not need choice. We still need to believe in set theory for this way to work, though.

**Syntactically**: Suppose we can derive a contradiction $\phi\land\neg\phi$ (with no free variables) from ZFC. Then it has a formal proof. Write down the relativization of each step in the proof to $\mathbf L$, and for each axioms in the proof insert our proof that $\mathbf L$ satisfies all axioms of ZFC.

The result is a proof in ZF of $(\phi\land\neg\phi)^{\mathbf L}$ which is the same as $\phi^{\mathbf L}\land \neg\phi^{\mathbf L}$, and therefore a bona fide contradiction proved from ZF. So if ZFC is inconsistent then ZF is inconsistent too.

Note that the syntactic method does not depend on having any model or universe for ZF or ZFC at all -- it proceeds entirely on the level of rules and proof. Thus it can be carried out in PA and is generally considered "finitistic".

Comment: Even in very weak fragments of $\sf PA$, actually!

Comment: Isn't it important that the proof from ZFC only needs finitely many axioms (so we can prove those instances of the axioms)?

Comment: Henning, not quite true. You can still do this with forcing and meta-induction on sentences (or by meta-compactness argument). Suppose that $\sf ZFC$ would prove $\varphi$, then there is a finite fragment which proves $\varphi$ and suffices for developing forcing. By the reflection theorem there is some $M$ which is a countable transitive model of that finite fragment, so $\varphi$ holds in $M$. Now use forcing in $M$ and the countability of $M$ in $V$ to generate a generic and in $M[G]$ all the axioms *from* $\sf ZFC$ still hold, but $\varphi$ now fails. Alternatively, [...]

Comment: [...] given any finite fragment of $\sf ZFC$ extend it to a slightly larger theory which suffices for developing forcing. Again reflect it to a countable transitive model, and with forcing over that model, we have that $\varphi$ is consistent with the finite fragment of $\sf ZFC$. Therefore by meta-compactness every finite fragment of $\sf ZFC$ is consistent with $\varphi$ so $\sf ZFC$ is consistent with $\varphi$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The latter alternative was what was I intended, but it same out as horrible nonsense, because I somehow typed "impossible" where I meant to say "important" ... :-(

Comment: It's impossible to note the difference between "important" and "impossible"! :-P

Comment: Corrected reply to @RobArthan: Not for the syntactic argument. You can just have proofs of all the axioms ready and insert whichever of them the proof-of-contradiction needs when you translate it. Needing only finitely many axioms is important for consistency proofs by _forcing_, where you need to start with a countable transitive model, and the assumption that such a thing exists for all of ZFC is stronger than assuming that it does for finite subsets of ZFC.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: so I am confused: on what assumptions have you proved that the axioms of ZFC *all* hold in $\mathbf{L}$? If you have proved them all with no assumptions, then you have proved in ZF that ZFC has a model and hence is consistent. (I am completely happy with the fishy semantic argument, but find the syntactic version much fishier :-).)

Comment: @Rob: No so fast -- **L** is a proper class, so ZF itself can't speak about truth in **L** of an arbitrary formula. Therefore ZF can't speak of **L** as a model. Without that ZF can't appeal to the soundness theorem (which is proved by showing that truth in the model is closed under entailment, so only true statements are provable) to conclude that ZFC is consistent.

Comment: @Rob: Further on, the core arguing in the syntactic argument happens _at the metalevel_. Looking at ZF from the outside we convince ourselves that each axiom of ZFC, relativized to **L**, _separately_ has a proof in ZF. ZF itself cannot speak of the totality of those proofs -- well it can, but only as a property of formal system, not as saying something about truth in its own universe.